Flutter: (fl_chart) Avoid re-rendering of grid lines in bar chart, when data points or maxY is changed
I am working with bar chart of the package fl_chart. Whenever I change the data points of the chart, the grid lines behind the bars change as well. I want to avoid the re-rendering of the grid lines. Is there any possible way to do this? I'm willing to make changes in the core code as well as i'm using the package locally for a personal project.
